# flex justify-content:space-between not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to get three boxes to distribute horizonatll across a div to the EDGES of that div using flex box. I need to use  justify-content: space-between; as per [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_justify_space-between)

However I have an extra div (that is generated by wordpress)
so my html is:

```
<div class="locationHolder">
  <div class="textwidget"> <!-- extra div-->
    <div class="locationSquare">...</div>
   <div class="locationSquare">...</div>
   <div class="locationSquare">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If i do this css:

```
page-template-home-page .locationHolder .textwidget{
 display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width:100%;
    background:green;
}

.page-template-home-page .locationSquare {
    width:30.942%;
    background:#fff;
    margin:0;
}
```

I get spaces at the far left and far right - the outside boxes don't go to the edge. If I remove the `<div class="textwidget">` and its `</div>` then it works fine.

If I put locationHolder as display:flex etc it doesn't work

I could remove the extra div with jQ but is there a css solution to overcome this?

Comment: Can you add a working plunker?

Comment: Seems to be working fine.. https://jsfiddle.net/ceyqvw96/

Comment: not sure what a 'working plunker' is - yes, the fiddle does work ... so why not here then http://www.restore.ee-web.co.uk/

Comment: it looks good to me, so maybe check if you have any styles for `.textwidget` like padding or margin?

Comment: @maxelcat Because the width of its' grandparent.. `site-content` has a 1170px width.

Comment: its not hte site-content width:1170px

Comment: i have added margin:0 to .textwidget and .locationSquare and checked code for missing things. nothing missing that I can see.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add `.textwidget::before, .textwidget::after { content: none; }`. You have `content: ""` added in line 1341 for this element and it breaks flex. Or just remove `.textwidget::before, .textwidget::after` from line 1341 ;)

Comment: I tried - and it went at the start so I added .textwidget::after {content: none;} and its works. its been driving me nuts for about an hour. I just couldn't see it so thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the issue and read many articles and could find a solution. I honestly though it was a flexbox bug and was about to report it. Finally found the cause for the problem.

If you are having psudo elements in your flex item, those items will also be flexed.

```
element{
    margin: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
}


element:before, element:after{
    content: none;
}
```

> If you have imported Bootstrap this is likely to happen more often because Bootstrap adds pseudo elements to clear floats.

If you want to use pseudo elements in a flex container which doesn't need to flow, you can position them absolute.

**Quoted from the specification >**

> As it is out-of-flow, an absolutely-positioned child of a flex
>   container does not participate in flex layout